# Blender use texture on cube side

Tags: texturing

[image: 1]

I am here in blender trying to Paint this selected side with the texture i made. I am completely new to this. Can someone explain to me how to do this ? I want to color to be saved with the .fbx, not separately or anything complicated. Just paint this side with this texture. Please guide me.

I have selected texture003 on the left panel. What else i am supposed to do ? I am lost here.

Answer (score 3):

*I am no specialist for exporting other formats (like .fbx), but in general it's like this:*

To add a texture only to the side you will need a second material.

Click the **material tab** and click `+` to add a new material.
Then click `+ New`.

Get into **Edit-Mode** and **select the face** you want to apply the material to.
With it selected click `Assign` under the materials.

This will assign the new Material only to that specific face.

Keep the new material selected in the material tab.
Then click the texture tab and add your texture to it by clicking `+ New`, selecting `Image or Movie`(should be default) and sroll down to `Image` and `Open` your Image Texture.

Positioning of the texture can be performed by the options below the `Image` part.

Comment: I don't have an image texture. I have a colored texture with blend mode i made in the texture tab as you can see in my screenshot, texture003, how do i assign that on my selected side of the cube ?

Comment: Oh I see, you don't meen to set a image. But still this should the same - try the steps described in my answer.

Comment: The material now has a textured that comes with it, right ? i can see it in preview. then i click assign, and i see a grey color, what is happening ? http://i.imgur.com/HI5cuDz.png

Comment: Correct. Try a test-render, it shound be visible. If it is bad positioned on the face, try selecting the face in Edit Mode and press `U` to unwrap. Then select the UV Map in the `Mapping` part of the texture tab, to make your texture follow the UV-Map.

Comment: if you look at the screenshot in the comments and in the question, i have done exactly what you described, and the color of the side doesn't change when i click assign, i want to paint my side with a blend color. do you have any other simpler method ?

Comment: Is there no blend tool (gradient color tool) in the materials tab ?

Comment: As far as I know, there is only this texture method. If there are questions left, please look for videos online describing color gradients on materials / textures in blender, that should be much easier to follow.